# How can I create a node on Liquid Sidechain?

Tags: sidechains

I want to create a node on Liquid Sidechain so that I can integrate Liquid Network with my decentralized exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The Liquid sidechain is a private sidechain. To get access to it, you must contact Blockstream. See https://blockstream.com/liquid/

Comment: Liquid is a private sidechain built on top of the open source Elements platform https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/

Comment: And what about Lightning Network? Is it a private sidechain as well?

Comment: The Lightning Network is not a sidechain. It is a completely different technology and layer on top of Bitcoin. It is not private; anyone can use LN and implement software that works with it. It is not centralized either.